# Python Value Error: Duplicated level name: "variable", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0

Tags: python-3.x, loops, logic, pandas-groupby, valueerror

I am using this below code for multiple charts visualization:

```
data.groupby(['y', 'y']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=plt.subplot(6,2,2+1),figsize=(15,25))
```

But getting the following error:

```
Duplicated level name: "y", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0.
```

whereas if I writing the same above code for other variable its working for example:

```
data.groupby(['otherObj', 'y']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=plt.subplot(6,2,2+1),figsize=(15,25))
```

How can the above error be sorted?

Comment: What do you expect to get by grouping by the same column multiple times?

Comment: multiple charts by using loop